# How do I write image to a specific directory with fs module in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fs

This is my current code:

```
await createCollage(pfparray, collageWidth).then((imageBuffer) => {
        pfpcollage = new MessageAttachment(imageBuffer, 'collage.png');
        fs.writeFile(`./images/${params.msg.author.id}.png`, imageBuffer, () => console.log('image downloaded'));
        }).catch(e => params.msg.channel.send({embed: {title: "Could not generate collage",description: e + " | error!"}})); 
             }
```

So when run, its supposed to save the image file in directory "images" with the author's id as name. However it console logs but does not actually save anything in the directory. This happens when I try saving to any specific directory. When i just try to save "${params.msg.author.id}.png" without any directory it saves it in the same directory correctly. What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you running this on windows platform or mac/linux platform?

Comment: @h-sifat I'm running this on Docker, so yeah linux i think

Comment: First import the path module, then try this for the path argument in the writeFile: path.join(__dirname, "image", "your image name")

Comment: @h-sifat Hey, someone else recommended me something similar. You were correct, the path was not being resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @h-sifat showed me, it seems the path was not being resolved. I imported the path module (Typescript [TS1259] hit an error here), I had to do

> import * as path from 'path'

After, I updated my code to this:

```
fs.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname,`./images/${params.msg.author.id}.png`), imageBuffer, () => console.log('image downloaded'));
```

This seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Seems like you are using typescript so you can write the import line as :  import path from 'path'. Because path is the default export you don't need to use the "* as " keyword. You can give any name you want, e.g., import bla_bla_bla from "path".

Comment: @h-sifat Yeah I actually did do that, but I hit error TS1259, a github issue about it told me to use import * as path from 'path'